# iptables NAT not being applied to packets coming from dummynet

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, ubuntu-14.04, ipfw

I have a setup where I have multiple interface aliases (with private IPs) for the primary network interface (`eth0`).

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet   HWaddr 0a:ed:01:17:53:b4
          inet addr:10.0.1.220  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet    HWaddr 0a:ed:01:17:53:b4
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet    HWaddr 0a:ed:01:17:53:b4
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

I am applying different network shaping policies to each of these aliases separately. In order for processes bound to each of these private IPs to be able to talk to the internet, I am using `iptables` as a NAT to masquerade the IP address to that of `eth0`

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.1/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This works great. If I watch the traffic leaving `eth0`, I can see that the source IP is properly changed.

```
# Send pings using eth0:0
ping -I 192.168.1.1 www.google.com

# Monitor packets sent out of eth0
tcpdump -i eth0 icmp

# 21:34:18.664664 IP ip-10-0-1-220.ec2.internal > ord37s08-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 3957, seq 2, length 64
# 21:34:18.683022 IP ord37s08-in-f4.1e100.net > ip-10-0-1-220.ec2.internal: ICMP echo reply, id 3957, seq 2, length 64
# 21:34:19.666137 IP ip-10-0-1-220.ec2.internal > ord37s08-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 3957, seq 3, length 64
# 21:34:19.683954 IP ord37s08-in-f4.1e100.net > ip-10-0-1-220.ec2.internal: ICMP echo reply, id 3957, seq 3, length 64
# 21:34:28.774873 IP ip-10-0-1-220.ec2.internal > ord37s08-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 3962, seq 1, length 64
# 21:34:28.793410 IP ord37s08-in-f4.1e100.net > ip-10-0-1-220.ec2.internal: ICMP echo reply, id 3962, seq 1, length 64
```

For traffic shaping, I'm using dummynet+ipfw. When I go to create the necessary traffic shaping policies for each of my aliases.

```
# Apply an outbound bandwidth cap of 1Mbps to eth0:0
ipfw pipe 1 config bw 1Mbit/s
ipfw queue 1 config pipe 1 queue 100
ipfw add queue 1 ip from 192.168.1.1 to any
```

Then the packets generated by dummynet are never actually seen by `iptables`, and therefore when the traffic leaves `eth0`, it has the internal private IP which obviously is never going to get a reply.

```
# Send pings using eth0:0
ping -I 192.168.1.1 www.google.com

# Monitor packets sent out of eth0
tcpdump -i eth0 icmp

# 21:34:29.776431 IP 192.168.1.1 > ord37s08-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 3962, seq 2, length 64
# 21:34:30.784435 IP 192.168.1.1 > ord37s08-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 3962, seq 3, length 64
# 21:34:31.792440 IP 192.168.1.1 > ord37s08-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 3962, seq 4, length 64
# 21:34:32.800446 IP 192.168.1.1 > ord37s08-in-f4.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 3962, seq 5, length 64
```

When I look at `iptables -t nat -vnL` I can confirm that the packets are never seen by `iptables`.

I realize that both `ipfw` and `iptables` are using the underlying `netfilter` library to handle packets, and based on my reading, they both hook into the `POSTROUTING` hooks. Is it possible that they are competing in some way? If so, can I somehow "re-order" the rules in `netfilter` such that dummynet will reinject the packet back into the flow so that it's picked up by `iptables`?  Is there an alternative way to create a NAT for these private IPs so that I can avoid this conflict?

Unfortunately, the NAT functionality of `ipfw` seems to have been dropped when porting it to Linux, so that's not a possibility.

**Update**

When digging into the dummynet code, it seems as though it re-injects the delayed packets into the stack using `dst_output` ([here](https://github.com/luigirizzo/dummynet/blob/e717cdd4bef764a4aa7babedc54220b35b04c777/kipfw/ipfw2_mod.c#L349-L369)) which based on my [reading](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/02/06/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-sending-data/#ip_output) should call `ip_output` which in turn should execute the `NF_INET_POST_ROUTING` netfilter hook.

When adding some `TRACE` `iptables` rules,

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw  -p icmp -j TRACE
iptables -A OUTPUT -t raw  -p icmp -j TRACE
```

I got the following.

Without dummynet running (but using the interface alias):

```
[23416.053128] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:2 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=172.217.7.164 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=37956 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=1 UID=0 GID=0
[23416.053136] TRACE: nat:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=172.217.7.164 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=37956 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=1 UID=0 GID=0
[23416.053139] TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=172.217.7.164 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=37956 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=1 UID=0 GID=0
[23416.053143] TRACE: nat:POSTROUTING:rule:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=172.217.7.164 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=37956 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=1 UID=0 GID=0
[23416.055612] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=0a:0d:f8:70:35:b4:0a:86:45:e6:5c:49:08:00 SRC=172.217.7.164 DST=10.0.1.255 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=0 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=1
[23416.055628] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=0a:0d:f8:70:35:b4:0a:86:45:e6:5c:49:08:00 SRC=172.217.7.164 DST=192.168.1.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=0 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=1
[23417.054547] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:2 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=172.217.7.164 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38092 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=2 UID=0 GID=0
[23417.054557] TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=172.217.7.164 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38092 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=2 UID=0 GID=0
[23417.055950] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=0a:0d:f8:70:35:b4:0a:86:45:e6:5c:49:08:00 SRC=172.217.7.164 DST=10.0.1.255 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=0 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=2
[23417.055969] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=0a:0d:f8:70:35:b4:0a:86:45:e6:5c:49:08:00 SRC=172.217.7.164 DST=192.168.1.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=0 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=2
[23418.056141] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:2 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=172.217.7.164 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38099 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=3 UID=0 GID=0
[23418.056157] TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=172.217.7.164 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38099 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=3 UID=0 GID=0
[23418.057635] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=0a:0d:f8:70:35:b4:0a:86:45:e6:5c:49:08:00 SRC=172.217.7.164 DST=10.0.1.255 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=0 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=3
[23418.057646] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=0a:0d:f8:70:35:b4:0a:86:45:e6:5c:49:08:00 SRC=172.217.7.164 DST=192.168.1.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=0 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=12659 SEQ=3
```

And with dummynet running (you can see that the `POSTROUTING` NAT policy is never applied.

```
[23535.355649] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:2 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=216.58.217.132 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43670 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12715 SEQ=1 UID=0 GID=0
[23535.355657] TRACE: nat:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=216.58.217.132 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43670 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12715 SEQ=1 UID=0 GID=0
[23535.355661] TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=216.58.217.132 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43670 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12715 SEQ=1 UID=0 GID=0
[23536.362312] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:2 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=216.58.217.132 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43689 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12715 SEQ=2 UID=0 GID=0
[23536.362324] TRACE: nat:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=216.58.217.132 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43689 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12715 SEQ=2 UID=0 GID=0
[23536.362330] TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=216.58.217.132 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43689 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12715 SEQ=2 UID=0 GID=0
[23537.370345] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:2 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=216.58.217.132 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43819 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12715 SEQ=3 UID=0 GID=0
[23537.370379] TRACE: nat:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=216.58.217.132 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43819 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12715 SEQ=3 UID=0 GID=0
[23537.370385] TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=216.58.217.132 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43819 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=12715 SEQ=3 UID=0 GID=0
```

Comment: What does a netfilter trace of the packets say?

Comment: @womble I added some `TRACE` rules to `iptables` to look at the flow of the packets and have updated the question with this info. Is there a better command to run that would allow me to trace the packets even when they enter/leave dummynet?